# Tensors - need materials to study

Tags: reference-request, tensors

I want to study about tensors. Can you indicate me some materials, papers, books which I should begin. I tried last year to study but it seems to hard for me. 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: If you're still in the game, you might want to look at these notes I just came across: http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an introduction that is suitable for someone with a mathematical temperament, see [**A Brief on Tensor Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038794088X) by James G. Simmonds.

For an introduction that is suitable for someone with a physics and engineering temperament, see [**A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521171903) by Daniel Fleisch.

Answer (score 3):

Several sets of notes can be found here by a great teacher - Keith Conrad:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/

Also by Fields Medal winner Timothy Gowers:

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html